# DecimalFormat and Double exception

Tags: java, android, double

i have a piechart and when i click on a slice it should show the percent in Toast but it throw an exception.

```
double[] distribution = { 4.2, 29.3, 12.1, 32.2, 10.1, 12.1 } ;

...

double value = seriesSelection.getXValue();
DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selectedSeries + " : "  + double.valueOf(dFormat.format(value)) + " % " ,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And i got this exception on `value` :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "32,2"
```

Comment: it should be 32.2 not 32,2

Comment: Yeah it should be 32.2 but i dont know why turned it 32,2

Comment: how is seriusSelection related to distribution?

Comment: You get the slice's name (and index) by it, (i have 6 slice) eg:Honeycomb 32.2% so if u clicked on honycomb slice then: double value = Honeycomb.getxValue();

Comment: @SanyiSajtos so its not related to distribution array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your local use a comma "," as a decimal separation. In order to get the english "." as a decimal separator, you will have to declare:

```
DecimalFormat dFormat =new DecimalFormat("#.#", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH));
```

Comment: I Love U, that was the problem :)